# Tomorrow used as an adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Is the following sentence correct?

> > He has given me a lot of documents to read before the presentation tomorrow.

I think it should be

> > > > He has given me a lot of documents to read before tomorrow's presentation.

Because tomorrow can not be used as an adjective

Comment: Both your examples are fine and mean the same thing. "Tomorrow" is a noun in both cases.

Comment: ...also in contexts like *...before **tomorrow** night*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temporal adverb before nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115263/temporal-adverb-before-nouns)